# 3D graphics engine for embedded Linux without Android

Tags: android, linux, opengl-es, embedded, unity-game-engine

I am facing a task to introduce some custom yet to be written written 3D games into our embedded Linux board. Our system is a custom Linux distribution. Main application is running with Qt and the plan is for this application to run games as separate processes that will overtake the screen while active. The board is capable of OpenGL ES2 and is on par with modern phones.

What are my options for a good, performant 3D graphics engine on such a platform?

Preferably I would love to have Unity3D, but it only supports Android. (Maybe there is a possibility to skip Android by providing only basic dependencies instead?)

Comment: Not really sure but ogre3d (http://www.ogre3d.org/) might be worth a look.

Comment: Ogre3d is a nice project but the resulting graphics does not look very impressive (judging solely from youtube)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [www.inka3d.com](http://www.inka3d.com). The same engine also works on embedded `linux` with some more features (e.g. clip libraries of Maya can be used). Currently it works on `BeagleBoard` even with character animation at 30 fps and `1024x768`.

Answer (score -1):

Since you've decided on Qt for your UI, you definitely want a graphics library that's compatible with Qt.

So it sounds like OpenGL ES is exactly what you're looking for:

> http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qt-embeddedlinux-opengl.html
>
> Qt for Embedded Linux provides support for integrating OpenGL ES for
>   drawing into a QGLWidget. The current implementation supports OpenGL
>   and 2D painting within a QGLWidget.

Q: Exactly what's holding you back (you didn't specify the exact board or any details about your toolchain/library vendors)?

PS:
You might also wish to look here:

> http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qt-embeddedlinux-opengl.html
>
> The reference integration for OpenGL into Qt for Embedded Linux is for
>   the PowerVR chipset from [Imagination Technologies](http://www.imgtec.com/). It consists of
>   two components: pvreglscreen, which provides the Qt for Embedded Linux
>   screen driver, and QWSWSEGL, which implements a plug-in to the PowerVR
>   EGL implementation to implement low-level OpenGL drawing surfaces.

PPS:
This is a great, great book on Linux Embedded: satisfaction guaranteed:

Embedded Linux Primer, Christopher Hallinan:

[http://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Linux-Primer-Practical-Real-World/dp/0137017839/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137017839)

Comment: Thank you for the attention on my problem. Actually the apps can run in any environment as I mentioned that Qt is only the starting app, manager and thus Qt compatibility is not a requirement. I did not specify any vendors to not stray from the problem at hand but if it becomes relevant I am happy to provide them. Furthermore, bare OpenGL ES is very different from rich 3D game engines. I would not ask for game engines if I did not want 90% of the things already implemented.